# jQuery interaction needs a Spring cleaning

Tags: jquery, dom, animation

I am using some jQuery interaction on a new site I'm building. The only problem is, I know only enough about it to be dangerous. Can someone help me clean this up? Works great, I just don't want to "splash" into the dom as much as I am. I'm sure there's a condensed way to accomplish this same thing. The ".rotate" function is actually calling a plugin that rotates images which I later manipulate in other ways. Thanks

```
(function($){})(window.jQuery);

$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#header").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 1000);

  $("#home_2").rotate(-10);
  $("#home_3").rotate(10);
  $("#home_4").rotate(20);
  $("#home_5").rotate(-20);

  var width = $(window).width();
  $("#home_5").animate({ left: 44 + '%', opacity: "1" }, 1000);
  $("#home_4").delay(2000).animate({ right: 44 + '%', opacity: "1" }, 1000);
  $("#home_2").delay(6000).animate({ left: 48 + '%', opacity: "1" }, 1000);
  $("#home_3").delay(4000).animate({ right: 48 + '%', opacity: "1" }, 1000);
  $("#home_1").delay(8000).animate({ top: 200 + 'px', opacity: "1" }, 1000);

  var loc = window.location.href;
    $("nav ul li a").each(function() {
      if(this.href == loc) {
         $(this).addClass('current');
      }
    });

  $("#home_5").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('stack_top');
    $("#home_4,#home_3,#home_2,#home_1").removeClass('stack_top');
  });
  $("#home_4").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('stack_top');
    $("#home_5,#home_3,#home_2,#home_1").removeClass('stack_top');
  });
  $("#home_3").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('stack_top');
    $("#home_4,#home_5,#home_2,#home_1").removeClass('stack_top');
  });
  $("#home_2").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('stack_top');
    $("#home_4,#home_3,#home_5,#home_1").removeClass('stack_top');
  });
  $("#home_1").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('stack_top');
    $("#home_4,#home_3,#home_2,#home_5").removeClass('stack_top');
  });

});
```

Comment: you are using lots of ID's, consider class.  then you can generalize which class gets a jQuery statement that all buttons have in common.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this.

Comment: What do you use `(function($){})(window.jQuery);` for? I can see what it is but why are you using it?

Comment: This was in the html5 Reset theme for Wordpress as best practice. Don't even know what it does.

Comment: Also on the id thing. I am treating each image a bit different. Didn't see a way to group them.

Comment: @Stefan its to say that the $ is always a reference to the jQuery object. but just having it there and not run anything inside it there is no need to have it in your code at all.

Comment: @voigtan I´m well aware of what it does and why it´s used but not why it´s implemented in this code example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where using class for similar elements will save a lot of repetitive code

```
/* adding the class would usually be done in your html markup but will add class dymamically here*/
$('#home_1, #home_2,  #home_3,  #home_4, #home_5').addClass('home_class')

/* one handler for all the elements in class*/
$('.home_class').click(function(e) {

    $('.stack_top').removeClass('stack_top');

    $(this).addClass('stack_top');
  });
```

Comment: I think I tried that... but the images are in a pile and when I click 1 I want only that 1 to come to the top, not all of them.

Comment: try again, this is normal way to consolidate and use class ..is same result as using "not" from other answer

Comment: one issue with the code is that you always add a stack_top, but I think @arnonate wants a toggle action.

Answer (score 2):

Or you just save all your items in one collection and filter it out:

```
var home = $('#home_1, #home_2,  #home_3,  #home_4, #home_5');

home.click(function() {
    home.not(this).removeClass('stack_top');
    $(this).toggleClass('stack_top');
});
```

but you should consider using css classes instead.

a js fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yF4gp/

Comment: Sweet bro, didn't even know there was a "not(this)" property. That seriously minimizes things.